# Google apps script колонка времени внесения изменений в ячейках другой колонки

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь разобраться в написании скриптов для гугл таблиц, не могу решить следующую задачу:

Есть колонка "А" на листе 1, где в каждую ячейку ежедневно вносятся изменения.
Как создать колонку "А" на листе 2, где в каждую ячейку будут вноситься даты времени внесения изменений в колонку "А" из 1 листа? Что бы была возможность проверять время когда были внесены изменения в ту или иную ячейку в столбце "А" на листе 1.

Я так понимаю тут используется функция onEdit:

function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}

Начинаться код должен с функции  editTables(//ID документа//)

Но это всё в чём мне удалось разобраться. Не могу разобраться как назначать диапазоны, ячейки, столбцы и строки в гугл таблицах что бы как то продвинуться вперёд.

Если кто знает как реализовать этот скрипт, прошу помочь.

Вот пример того как это должно выглядеть в результате:
[image: Рис. 1 (Столбец "А" на листе 1 куда вносятся изменения)]
[image: Рис. 2 (Столбец "А" на листе 2 куда вносятся даты времени внесения изменений в колонку "А" на листе 1 изображённой на рис 1)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно что-то вроде этого

```
function onEdit(e) {

    try {

        if (!e || !e.range) return;

        if (e.range.getColumn() === 1 && e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Sheet1')
            e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, 1).setValue(new Date());

    } catch (err) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err.message);
    }

}
```

- сначала мы проверяем наличие правильного аргумента, переданного в функцию
- далее проверяется состояние - является ли изменяемая ячейка колонкой `A` листа `Sheet1`
- при исполнении условия, вносятся изменения в `Sheet2`
- добавлен перехват ошибок

Comment: Огромная благодарность! Очень помогли!